# Fitting all components into Applet

Tags: java, macos, applet

I'm currently trying to make a basic applet that can tell me the sum of two numbers entered in JTextFields. My first step is getting everything formatted in the applet before I add listeners to get input and calculate. When I run my program, the only thing that appears is one component, taking up the whole window. How would I fix this?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class calculator extends JApplet {

    private JTextField num1;
    private JTextField num2;
    private JButton calculate;
    private JLabel result;
    private double sum;


    public void init() {
        num1 = new JTextField();
        num2 = new JTextField();
        calculate = new JButton();
        result = new JLabel();

        add(num1);
        add(num2);
        add(calculate);
        add(result);

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix your problem by adding a layout manager.

Try adding these lines to your code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

Edit: For anyone else viewing this, the correct issue was that super.paint(g); was not being called.

Comment: When I added FlowLayout, the two JTextFields were the only components to come up, and both were extremely small

Comment: Try removing your paint function as well, or call super.paint(g); inside of it.

Comment: Have you tried giving them some default text? It is possible that java is resizing the components to their minimum size (0) without text.  Layout managers can be annoying.

Comment: super.paint(g);  //this calls the paint function of the parent class (in this case, JApplet)

Comment: I was able to correct the issue by adding ("",15) parameters to the JTextField, but now my listeners are giving me trouble (sorry for lack of experience with applets / listeners, doing this for the first time for school). I'm not sure if this is the best way to add code to comments, but here is the few lines I have for listeners: http://pastebin.com/sC2Qk3Xs

Comment: You really shouldn't need listeners for the text fields, you just need a listener for the button.  Try something like this: http://pastebin.com/jeNAVQJa - if I remember right you have to declare variables as final if you want to access them from within a sub class.